# jquery increase/decrease image contrast on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This site I am developing is using HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap 4, and Jquery. I would like to have a scroll effect on a full-screen background-image that is at the very top of my page (100vh hero banner type thing). I am trying to gradually increase the contrast (css filter: contrast(some%)) of an image as the user scrolls down (its fine if the image is completely unrecognizable by the time it leaves viewport).

I have some Jquery that somewhat does the effect I am looking for, however I would like the effect to be more gradual.

The main issue I am having is that when the user scrolls back to the top of the page the contrast value gets set to 0% leaving a completely grayed out image. What I would like is for the contrast to gradually decrease back to normal (100%) as the user scrolls back up all the way to the top of the page.

I have set up a very simplified codepen. I couldn't get a css background-image url value to reference an external link from codepen, so I am targeting the effect on a full screen image ().

Thanks!

```
Link to the Pen: [codepen-link][1]


[1]: http://codepen.io/wdzajicek/pen/MVovZE
```

See code below in snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
      $(window).scroll(function(){
        var pixelstop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(".myimage ").css("filter", "contrast(" + pixelstop + "%)");
      });
    });
```

```css
.header {
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .myimage {
      position:absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      width; 100%;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    .jumbotron {
      position: relative;
      background-color: unset;
      margin-top: 150px;
      z-index: 999;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header text-center">
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wdzajicek/portfolio/master/assets/img/header-bg.jpg" class="myimage" alt="">
    </header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the main problem in `$(window).scrollTop();` it will return 0 value
that's why contrast value gets set to 0% leaving a completely grayed out image

```
var pixelstop = $(window).scrollTop();
```

replace the code with

```
var pixelstop = 100+100*$(window).scrollTop()/$(window).height();
```

don't just copy this code please understand thanks.

Comment: Thank you.  I knew that 0% contrast was the issue and logically my code would set the contrast to 0% when that value is taken from .scrollTop() which equals 0 at the page top. I was trying to make it work before by trying to add 100 to the pixelstop within the .css (...) rules which was giving me 1000% at the top (just adding 100 to the front of the pixelstop value).  This code is exactly what I wanted because increasing the second 100 in var pixelstop exaggerates the effect, allowing me to fine tune it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    
    var pixelstop = 100+100*$(window).scrollTop()/$(window).height();
    console.log(pixelstop);
    $(".myimage ").css("filter", "contrast(" + pixelstop + "%)");
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  height: 100vh;
}

.myimage {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  width; 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  background-color: unset;
  margin-top: 150px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header text-center">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wdzajicek/portfolio/master/assets/img/header-bg.jpg" class="myimage" alt="">
</header>
```

100 is default value of filter contrast not 0. that's why the background is grey out because it reaches zero.